# Exporting data to multiple excel files on the server side

Tags: export-to-excel, application-server

This is more of a design question-

In our web based app, that has a concurrency of 300 users, there is a requirement to generate quarterly summary for our client entities, end of each quarter , meaning multiple excel files on the application server (offline processing). Having separate files for each entity is a requirement. there are about 5000 entities and hence I am talking about 5000 files to be generated. Each file may go upto 1MB max - zipped.

I am looking at suggestions about the best way to approach this requirement of generating a file for each entity. Generation of files (a job) is nightly and has to happen every quarter - exactly the last day of the quarter. The last day of the quarter could end up being a workday. Generation of 5000 files may get over, over the night, but I am not convinced about this approach. The files will be pushed to a file server the same day and available to respective subscribers.

Are there better ways to approach this requirement? What other alternative approaches could be considered for this?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the requirement is that the reports have to be generated exactly after the last day of the quarter then there is no other choice. You have to do it over night. I'm just wondering if a couple of hours will be enough for it. Maybe it will be necessary to run report generations in several concurrent jobs.

Comment: Agreed. Thats exactly where I am headed - Create files in parallel. The whole process of generating (all the) files may run into many hours, but this can be calculated precisely only after we decide other things such as "how" the file will be generated. Thanks for jumping in with the thought!